# Change MySQL query execution order

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to put a entry in the database with id of 2. In order to do that I'm moving all records having more than 2 to id + 1.

```
UPDATE
    `pedo_meta`
SET
    `id` = `id` + 1
WHERE
    `id` > 1;
```

Because id is a primary key. This query is failing saying :

`#1062 - Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'`. I know this is happening because query execution starts from top to bottom and when the query tries to make a the column having id 2 to id 3, a duplicate entry error occurs because id 3 column already exists.

I believe this problem can be solved if we reverse the order of execution. So the query starts by making id 537 to 538 then 536 to 537 and so on. So **is there any to reverse the order of execution for a query in MySQL**?

Comment: Try `WHERE id <> -1` if you want to hit all records

Comment: add a new column new_id, then update the `new_id = id +1`. And then a new update where `id` = `new_id`

Comment: If one wishes to "hit" all records can simply drop there `WHERE`. @Haris id's are not supposed to change. You're doing it wrong.

Comment: If the value of an id has some meaning beyond the internal scope of the database then don't use an ai. But a better idea is to not worry about the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` on the `UPDATE` statement to affect the order the rows are updated:

> If the `ORDER BY` clause is specified, the rows are updated in the order that is specified.
>   **source:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

So you can use the following `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE `pedo_meta`
SET `id` = `id` + 1
WHERE `id` > 1
ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d32378123615cccae9bd5a1946a3c17)

---

**Note:** If you want to change the sort order of items you shouldn't use the ID column. You can add an additional numeric column to define a sort order. The ID column should only be use to identify a record in the table.

Comment: This seems to be the most appropriate and simplest, fastest solution in this case. Just fix the semicolon in the code ````WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY id DESC;````

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple algorithm to accomplish that fast:
1. create a new column `new_id`
2. set `new_id = id + 1`
3. update `id` and set it to be `id = new_id`
4. remove column `new_id` when you are done

P.S. **IF** you want to sort your items after `id` is better to create a new column `sort_order` which can be updated extremely fast...